# How to double click an option in a multi select using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, multi-select

I have a multi select box that has options that you have to double click in order to send it to a 'Selected' field.  No matter what I try, I can't seem to get it to work.  The select html looks like so:

```
<select name="name1" id="id1" ondblclick="a lot of stuff">
    <option value='value1'>text1</option>
    <option value='value2'>text2</option>
    <option value='DoubleClickMe'>DoubleClickMe</option>
    <option value='value4'>text4</option>
    <option value='value5'>text5</option>
</select>
```

I want to double click the 'DoubleClickMe' value to send it over to another field.  I've tried:

```
ret = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='id1']/option[text()='DoubleClickMe']")

actionChains.double_click(ret).perform()
```

Originally, this would act like it was double clicking elsewhere on the page (at least highlight some other text).  Now... it seems to be selecting a bunch of options to send over, as if it was clicking a heck of a lot more than twice.  Similarly, I tried:

```
actionChains.click(ret).click(ret).perform()
```

This one is giving me the same results as the previous one.

While in debug mode (pdb), I tried spamming the following (each of which will select the option, but won't read it as a double click:

```
ret.click()

ret = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='id1']")
select = Select(ret)
select.select_by_visible_text("DoubleClickMe")

select.select_by_value("DoubleClickMe")
```

I tried sending those commands quick enough as to where, if working properly, it should easily be considered a double click.

Is there something that I'm missing or doing wrong?

I'm using:

```
Windows 7 64-bit
Selenium 2.44
Python 2.7
IE11
```

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing out ideas... havn't tested this though

(edited)

```
user = self.find_element_by_id("id1")
for option in user.find_elements_by_tag_name("option"):
   if option.text == "Option to be selected":
      option.click()
```

Comment: didn't work :/ it just selected the option; I tried with both double_click(option) and click(option)

Comment: Maybe try a different webpage? (not permanently of course, just to gauge if the webpage is just weird...)

Comment: I've tried 3 (each their own server) - maybe it just hates me

Comment: maybe it's an IE thing. try chrome

Comment: ah fixed it. I think... just use   option.click() (See newly edited code)

Comment: it needs to double click - that will only click it once

Comment: could you try disabling the javascript on the page? There probably requiring you to double click through javascript, because this works on a regular select element

Answer (score 0):

Try with below logic

```
menu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#id1")
option = menu.find_element_by_css_selector("option[value='DoubleClickMe']")

ActionChains(driver).double_click(option).perform()
```

Update 1

Try with below logic. 
First move the mouse to that element and try to double click without passing element.

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(option).double_click().perform()
Or
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(option).click().click().perform()
```

Comment: weird... it's doing that thing where it highlights text at the top left of the page... and if I move my mouse down, it's as if it's holding down the click (highlights everything I hover over)

Comment: I'm not so sure about python code(I work with Java + WebDriver).  I've just updated the locator of option element. Just give a try with that.

Comment: well it seems like the issue is with ActionChains.  if I do simply option.click(), it will single click the option (so it is finding the correct element).  However, when I try it in ActionChains, it goes funky

Comment: I've added another possible solution in my answer. Just give a try with that.

Comment: whenever I use ActionChains, it acts as if it's working on the top left of the screen (I'm trying to double click something that's in the middle-ish).  I've looked, and there is no html there that is even similar to the select box; also, if I just use option.click(), it will click the option properly - it just doesn't do it when using ActionChains